# Is there a Python analog to this C++ construct?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In C++ (and C?) you can use variables in if statements while keeping them local. For example instead of this:

```cpp
int out = func();
if (out == value) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

You can validate a value that you only need for a short block without adding the output variable to the calling context:

```cpp
if (int out = func(); out == value) {
  // out is accessible here
}
// But out is not accessible here
```

I haven't been able to find anything like this in Python. Just curious if there was a way to do something similar.

Comment: I think you are looking for the walrus operator `:=` which was introduced in Py3.8

Comment: Oh nice! yeah, that looks right. Make this answer?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon that doesn't limit the scope of the variable the way it does in C++.

Comment: Actually, no, but I’d like some way of scoping variables which is more local than a function/method/class, because the work I use Python for is a lot of basic sequential processing and it would be useful to have something like a `with var1=0,var2=None:` to give me a scope where var1 and var are present overriding any outer-scope definitions and then automatically deleted. Today if I want to do this I have to do extra work and indirection using functions, which feels like hard work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ allows you to use `=` in an expression.  Python does not.

[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) implemented first in Python 3.8 introduces *assignment expressions* using what is informally known as the walrus operator, `:=`.

It differs in the way that `=` works in C++ in that it doesn't limit the scope of the variable; you can still access it after the block where it was defined.

```
if (out := func()) == value:
    print(out)
print(out) # this works because out is still valid
```

To limit the scope you have to be explicit and `del` the variable.

```
if (out := func()) == value:
    print(out)
del out
print(out) # fails with an exception
```

Comment: Your example only deletes `out` when the predicate is `True`. Should probably move the `del` statement out of the `if` block.

Comment: Using an approach of manually adding `del` isn’t actually a direct answer to OP question which is about whether Python has a (automatic) local variable scope in a `for` loop. The real answer is no.

Comment: @barny you're free to leave your own answer.  Sometimes when what you really want can't be done, a workaround is useful.